# Positioning & sliding of HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I have a `div` which contains a `div` which contains two other `div`s:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="title">Some title</div>
        <div class="description">Some description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
div.container {
    width: 220px;
    height: 160px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

div.container div.overlay {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This, with some other, irrelevant, CSS, makes what's shown in the second picture. Now I need to make some other CSS to make it like the first picture by default. When you go with your mouse over `.container`, the `.description` should slide in, making it like the second picture:

[image] [image]

**I can't figure out how to position everything and let the description slide in. Can you?**

This question is only about positioning and the jQuery needed to slide the description in - colors and other layout isn't the problem. I'm looking for a solution compatible in all major browsers.

**EDIT**:

Forgot to mention that I do not know the height of `.title` or `.description` - the heights are set to `auto` because the depend on the text in there.

Comment: A better title would be very helpful, but I couldn't make up one. If you know one, please suggest an edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with pure css 3.

As it is not possible to have a height transition from `0` to `auto` it uses `max-height` instead:

```
.description  {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: 2s;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div.container div.overlay:hover .description {
  max-height: 160px;
}
```

pure **css** solution: http://jsfiddle.net/DkAKt/1/

This solution works even if you don't know the height of your description.

CSS 3 transitions require Internet Explorer 10+ : http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions .
Older versions will still work however without the animation.

---

If you can't live without an animation in IE 8-9 you have to use javascript:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".container").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(".description", this).stop(1,1).slideDown();  
  }).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(".description", this).stop(1,1).slideUp();  
  })
  .find('.description').slideUp(0);
});
```

pure **jQuery** solution: http://jsfiddle.net/DkAKt/2/

Comment: Since you are using CSS3 here is the fiddle with some effect - [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/DkAKt/3/) - Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a million! The jQuery solution hit the bulls eye. Short, clear, working. Great!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Javascript to do this because the solution depends upon knowing the height of the description. You mentioned jQuery — here's the code for that:

```
$(function slideDescriptionOnHover(){
    $('.container').each(function adjustOverlayPosition(){
        var $overlay     = $(this).find('.overlay');
        var $description = $(this).find('.description');

        function slideUp(){
            $overlay.animate('bottom', 0);
        };

        function slideDown(){
            $overlay.animate('bottom', -$description.height());
        };

        $(this).hover(slideUp,slideDown);

        $overlay.css('margin-bottom', -$description.height());
    });
});
```

I assumed you'd want to animate the effect: if not, replace the `animate` method with `css`.

A brief guide as to what's going on:

1. For each `.container` (they may have different height descriptions, depending on how much text each contains)…
2. Bind variables for the `.overlay`, which we'll want to animate, and the `.description`, whose height dictates how we want to animate.
3. Define 2 functions: one that sets `bottom` to `0`, ensuring the very bottom of the `.overlay` lines up with the `.container`'s bottom; and another which pulls the bottom of the `.overlay` down by the height of the `.description`.
4. Bind those two functions to the jQuery hover method (an alias for `mouseover` and `mouseout`)
5. …and finally, make sure the description is hidden to start with.

You'll also need to adjust the rule for `div.container`, such that it contains the property:

```
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Pure CSS Solution, you need to move the `.overlay` div a little bit down.

`bottom:-30px;`.

Then you don't wanna show that part, so add `overflow:hidden;` to `.container`.

Now, when you hover over it, you need to raise it up.

```
.overlay:hover
{
    bottom:0;
}
```

Now make it more **beautiful**, use `transition`.

```
.overlay
{
     bottom:-30px;
     -webkit-transition:bottom 2s;
        -moz-transition:bottom 2s;
          -o-transition:bottom 2s;
             transition:bottom 2s;
}
.overlay:hover
{
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I do not know the height of the title / description...

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward, add the following CSS:

```
div.container {
    overflow:hidden;
}

div.overlay {
    bottom:-30px;
    -webkit-transition:bottom 500ms;
    -moz-transition:bottom 500ms;
    -o-transition:bottom 500ms;
    transition:bottom 500ms;
}

div.description {
    height:30px;
}

div.container:hover > div.overlay {
    bottom:0;
}
```

That should do it. If not, remove the > selectors, they might be too specific.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I do not know the height of the title / description...